# Why when I press GO in iPad, does not focus next input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

Imagine that I have many div in `display: none;` and just the first one is in `visible`.

In the view, you can navigate through each one pressing a ENTER or GO (in an iPad). So when you want to advance, change the current div to `none`, and the next one change it to `visible`. But right now I wanna also set the focus in an input element where has a `focusable` class. But it does not set the focus.

Here is my code:

```
var setFocus = function () {
    $("#question-container2").find("#question:visible").find('.focusable')[0].focus();
    $("#question-container2").find("#question:visible").find('.focusable')[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
};

var nextPage = function () {
    if ($currentPage < $totalPages) {
        $currentPage++;
        $("#question-container2").find("#question:visible").hide().next().show();
    }
};

$(".input-area").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // Do something
        nextPage();
        setFocus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a tab index in your elements. This is a browser accessibility attribute which will tell the browser where to navigate to next when you are done with the current field.

See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/tabindex